# How to make Filter work with Jquery Table Sorter in this case?

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Table Sorter to display Data in form of a table 
I wanted to keep Search Functionality for the data present inside the table so for this i am referring the following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2566/

and i tried this way

```
<input class="search selectable" type="search" placeholder="Search" data-column="all" />

 $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch('#candletable', $('.search'));
```

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1501/

But this isn't filtering any data

Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Add this bind line inside `candlespattern` click event. Because initialising the filter when there is no data in table does not work. Plus pass the `filter` option in the tablesorter method.

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1503/).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#candletable').tablesorter({
      widgets: ["filter", "scroller"],
            widgetOptions: {
            scroller_height: 100,
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            filter_saveFilters: true,
            filter_reset: '.candlespattern'
        }

    }).tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        size: 20
        });

    $("#pager").hide();

     //$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch('#candletable', $('.search'));

});


var myjsonresponse1 = [{
    "name": "JAYBARMARU111",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
    "name": "JUSTDIAL1111",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
    "name": "TITAN111",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}];

var myjsonresponse2 = [{
    "name": "JAYBARMARU2222",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
    "name": "JUSTDIAL222",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
    "name": "TITAN222",
    "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}];

$(document).on("click", ".candlespattern", function() {

    var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
    var datatoselect = '';

    if (clicked === 'one') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
    } else if (clicked === 'two') {
        datatoselect = myjsonresponse2;
    }

    var html = "";
    html += '';
    for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" + datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
    }

    $("#candletable tbody").html(html);

    //binding filter here when data is added to table.
     $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch('#candletable', $('.search'));

    $("#candletable").trigger("update");

    $("#pager").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sahil , is it possible to reset filter when clicked on One Or Two Tabs ??

Comment: Yes it is possible to reset, just pass the class of the button which should act like reset button in `filter_reset`, in your case it is, `.candlespattern`. Please check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1503/) and answer.